# PlayerJoinEvent error with my configuration file

Tags: java, bukkit

I get an error every time I join with the join connected through the configuration file.

Main class:

```
    public Core plugin;

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {

        Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Events(), this);
        new DiscordCommand(this);
        new TeamspeakCommand(this);
        new cHubCommand(this);
        new PingCommand(this);
        new HelpCommand(this);
        new WebsiteCommand(this);
        new BuyCommand(this);
        new MenuCommand(this);

        getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
        saveConfig();
    }
```

Events class:

```
    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) {

        Player player = event.getPlayer();

        event.setJoinMessage(null);
        event.getPlayer().sendMessage(Core.getPlugin(null).getConfig().getString("joinmessage_1.", "§fWelcome to the official §acHub§f network!"));
        event.getPlayer().sendMessage(Core.getPlugin(null).getConfig().getString("joinmessage_1.", "§fWelcome to the official §acHub§f network!"));
        event.getPlayer().sendMessage(Core.getPlugin(null).getConfig().getString("joinmessage_2.", "§fIf you need any assistance, type §a/help"));
        event.getPlayer().sendMessage(Core.getPlugin(null).getConfig().getString("joinmessage_line_2.", "§7§m--------------------------------------"));
```

Console error:
https://pastebin.com/CDwK3UFj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with `Core.getPlugin(null)`. Method `getPlugin()` is from parents class JavaPlugin which your *Core.java* extends and you can't pass null as a argument.

If you want to refer to your plugin object (Core.java) you can change it to `Core.getPlugin(Core.class)` but more professional would be to pass reference to this class in constructor.

So, the beginning of your Events.class will look like:

```
Core plugin;

public Events(Core plugin){
    this.plugin = plugin;
}
```

and then you can simply do:

```
event.getPlayer().sendMessage(plugin.getConfig().getString("joinmessage_1.", "§fWelcome to the official §acHub§f network!"));
```

and in Core class you will change it to:

```
Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Events(this), this);
```